# Use local HTTP proxy over the internet

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

I have set up a local proxy server on Ubuntu Server (I used Squid). Now, when I'm on the same LAN of the server and when I connect to `192.168.1.XXX:8888` I can use the proxy. But can I use it over the internet? I have already tried connecting to the public IP address of my server but it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: You need to open the ports through your Internet router. This is hardware dependent - you'll need to consult your documentation. In any case, this is not a question for SO. Try [su]

Answer (score 0):

Your server must have a separate public IP address, or you have to use a specific port on your current IP and do a port redirection for incoming traffic on public IP and this specific port to the proxy server.